# Unwanted / added to html file-path

Tags: html, path, cherrypy

I currently have a python/cherrypy application where the first page served-up is index.html, which contains the link `<a href="designs.html">read more</a>`

When I click on this link cherrypy returns the following traceback:

404 Not Found

The path '/designs.html' was not found.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aharrisreid/webapps/cp32/lib/python3.1/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 646, in respond
response.body = self.handler()
File "/home/aharrisreid/webapps/cp32/lib/python3.1/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in **call**
self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/aharrisreid/webapps/cp32/lib/python3.1/cherrypy/_cperror.py", line 387, in **call**
raise self
cherrypy._cperror.NotFound: (404, "The path '/designs.html' was not found.")

Because the href attribute is 'designs.html' I expect this page to be called directly without calling cherrypy, but somewhere along the line a / prefix has been added to designs.html, hence cherrypy has been invoked to evaluate the root path.

How can I solve this problem, and ensure that only 'designs.html' is passed to the page processor?

TIA,
Alan

Comment: Do you use rewrite rules to have all requests handled by cherrypy? (as a Front Controller)

Comment: @Matijs - Sorry, not sure what you mean by rewrite rules.  What is a Front Controller?  Regards.

Comment: For a short description of a front controller, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Because the href attribute is 'designs.html' I expect this page to be called directly without calling cherrypy, but somewhere along the line a / prefix has been added to designs.html, hence cherrypy has been invoked to evaluate the root path.

I'm not sure what you mean by "directly"--*something* has to be invoked to evaluate any URL; if not CherryPy, what would you expect would be invoked? There's no facility for your browser to access files on the server without some form of intermediary.

If you want to serve static files instead of dynamic content using CherryPy, check out the staticfile and staticdir Tools, described at http://docs.cherrypy.org/dev/progguide/files/static.html

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I guess I was expecting that if a html file (without any path) was called via. a link in another html file then it would look for it automatically in the same folder (like it does via. a browser in test mode before I brought CherryPy into the equation).  However, if CP puts a '/' before a non-pathed file, that's ok - I'll create a new static sub-folder for all my non-dynamic html files and create a pointer to the folder in my configuration file.  Regards.